# Permissão para criar Banco de Dados negada pelo banco de dados 'master'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Eu estou tentando migrar o banco de dados criado automaticamente pelo Identity para controlar autenticação de usuários e aparece esse erro:

```
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

A minha connection string está assim:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=LPG-11;Initial Catalog=LPGPonto.Models.LPGPontoContext;Integrated Security=True;user id=sa;password=xxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Com esse mesmo usuário (sa - que é o Owner do banco de dados master) e senha eu consigo criar banco de dados normalmente pelo Management Studio, porém quando tento criar pela migração do Visual Studio ele dá esse erro. O usuário e senha estão corretos, o usuário "sa" tem permissão para tudo no SQL Server. O que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui criar. O erro estava na minha connection string, no parâmetro Secutity User.
Alterei deste forma e funcionou:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=LPG-11;Initial Catalog=LPGPonto.Models.LPGPontoContext;Integrated Security=False;user id=sa;password=xxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 1):

E a explicação do porquê funcionou quando foi criado novamente é porque quando o `Integrated Security=True` não há necessidade de colocar usuário e senha, pois a autenticação é feita pelo Windows, já no `Integrated Security=False`, o usuário e senha é obrigatório.

[The ultimate guide to connection strings in web.config](https://blog.elmah.io/the-ultimate-guide-to-connection-strings-in-web-config/)

[Connection String Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax)

[Manually Connecting to the DBServer](https://www1.citavi.com/sub/manual5/en/configure_connection_files_manually.html)